# Scrapy to elasticsearch bulk import?

Tags: elasticsearch, scrapy

I'm trying to output some data to the elasticsearch bulk import format. This requires two lines of JL, like so:

```
{"index": {"_type": "media", "_id": "https://macaulaylibrary.org/asset/75247", "_index": "audiomnia_dev"}}
{"description": "Macaulay Library ML75247; aracari sp.; Pteroglossus sp.; \u00a9\u00a0Curtis Marantz; Lago Sachavacaya Trail, right bank Rio Tambopata, Madre de Dios, Peru; 23 Aug 1994", "creator": "Curtis Marantz", "url": "https://macaulaylibrary.org/asset/75247", "image": "https://macaulaylibrary.org/media/Spectrograms/audio/image/320/0/75/75247.jpg", "commonName": "aracari sp.", "fileFormat": "audio", "sciName": "Pteroglossus sp.", "dateCreated": "1994-08-23T08:13:00", "geo": {"lat": "-12.9", "lon": "-69.3667"}, "contentLocation": "Lago Sachavacaya Trail, right bank Rio Tambopata, Madre de Dios, Peru", "name": "ML75247 aracari sp. Macaulay Library"}
```

Is there a way to do this reliably in Scrapy? I had the following, but race conditions happened and it messed up the order of the lines in some cases, which caused the Elasticsearch bulk API to barf:

```
yield { "index" : {
    "_index" : "audiomnia_dev",
    "_type" : "media",
    "_id" : json_ld["url"] }
}
yield json_ld
```

What's the right way to ensure that the two lines of jl together while still following the generator / yield pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the spider yield a single object with all relevant data, and write a custom [item exporter](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#topics-exporters) to format it properly for elasticsearch.